# To View a web page inside your app?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I needed to build an Android app that lets you view a web page inside my app. I needed this not to be in a browser but my app.
I found the answer and some options for when page is loaded.
I thought I'd try sharing the info I found here, after I tested of course.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First need to add INTERNET permission to your manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then, use the WebView class to display a web page.  First, create a layout that contains a webview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
<WebView android:id="@+id/myWebView"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Activity, (probably the onCreate), initialize a WebView object by using the layout you created.  An example is below.
    private WebView webview;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);

    String url = "http://bigdaddyapp.com";

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    //next line explained below
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(url);
}
```

If you'd like specific options, like catching pages as they load, you need an inner WebViewClient class.  For example, you can use the onPageStarted(...) method to do something whenever a new page is loaded in your webview:

```
 public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

  public MyWebViewClient() {
     super();
     //start anything you need to
  }

  public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
     //Do something to the urls, views, etc.
  }
 }
```