# Show google search results in edit text- WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView along with edit text as a search bar but instead of typing the whole url in the field, i want it to make searches also like "facebook" and "google" i found one answer here but i have no idea how to do it, can anybody help me with this?

[How to show Android Google default search results in webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955560/how-to-show-android-google-default-search-results-in-webview)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);//Enable Cookies
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//Enable Java Script
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/"); //Set Home page
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);//Remove ScrollBars
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(12);//Set Font Size
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);//Enable Image Loading
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);//Enable Flash
    mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH); //improves Feedback     on touch
    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);//Transparent Screen When Loading
    //mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//Set Zoom Controls 
    //mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);//Requires Api 11
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);//Set Cache (8mb)
    String appCachePath =     getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();//Set Cache (8mb)
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);//Set Cache (8mb)
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);//Set Cache (8mb)
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);//Set Cache (8mb)
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);//Set Cache (8mb)


}
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
{


webview.loadUrl(url);
return true;
}
}

 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {

 if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())

{
mWebView.goBack();
return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in that answer, you need to get the text you get from the `EditText` in the `onClick` method of the button and append it to the URL `https://www.google.com/search?q=query_string`

Comment: Have you learnt the basics of layouts and views? I don't see any EditText where you'd enter any search queries. (Not being rude or anything.)

Comment: Hmmm thought so. Well, you need to add an editText and a button. Enter the search query in the editText and in the onClick method of the button, you need to fetch the search query and do the operation I mentioned in the answer. If you don't know how to handle editText and buttons, you need to learn all that. It's pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Lol. Just learn the basics first. That includes views etc. Once you get the hang of it, we can continue from the web view. "Tab sir ke upar se nahi niklega" :P

Comment: Try this http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/04/android-simple-edittext-example.html

Comment: If you've created apps, then what can be the problem??

Comment: Which stage are you stuck on?

Comment: Refer the link I posted earlier in the comments. You need to create objects of the EditText and Button views and link them to the elements in the layout using findViewById().

Comment: In that case, you need to learn Java first man. You have to take it one step at a time.

Comment: Then just ask some friend who knows Java.